# Text terminals (ctrl+alt+F[1-6]) show dmesg output, don't allow login

Tags: 14.04, command-line, login

On a Ubuntu 14.04 maching, my text terminals (all 6 of them) instead of showing the login prompt, seem to show the last dmesg output from boot time. I can go back to the graphical desktop environment with f7, or toggle between text terminals, but none of them show the login prompt, all seem to be stuck on showing this dmesg screen.

Tried uncommenting GRUB_TERMINAL=console on my /etc/default/grub (a common solution for when text terminals show a blank screen) but it didn't seem to make a change.

If it makes a difference I am running dual monitors, one goes blank and the other one shows the aforementioned dmesg output, my experience when switching to text terminals in other computers with dual monitors is that one of them goes blank and the other one shows the login prompt.

Comment: Did you run "sudo update-grub" after changing that line?

Comment: Yes I did,  my issue doesn't seem to have the same cause than the blank screen problem I was referring to has.

Comment: Have you pressed a key in the terminal, to see if the login prompt appears ?

Comment: Yes, no change at all, when in the terminals the system doesn't seem to respond to any input (except ctrl+alt+f7, which gets me back to the gui)